# How to get symbolic link information for WSO2 Registry resource?

Tags: wso2

I found no information about this anywhere in the WSO2 documentation.

I have a [`Resource`](http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.5.0/docs/apidocs/kernel/org/wso2/carbon/registry/core/Resource.html) object obtained from a call to `UserRegistry.get(path)`, and this resource' media type (obtained from `resource.getMediaType()` is set to [`RegistryConstants.LINK_MEDIA_TYPE`](http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.5.0/docs/apidocs/kernel/org/wso2/carbon/registry/core/RegistryConstants.html#LINK_MEDIA_TYPE), indicating that it represents a symbolic link to another resource in the registry.

I would like to find out what the original media type is for the resource pointed to by this symbolic link. The WSO2 GREG management interface is apparently able to do this - clicking the `Info` button on a resource shows the media type I'm looking for - but there does not seem to be an API call that provides this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment you have to take those attributes using the properties.

registry.get("path to symlink").getProperties()

1) **registry.actualpath** : Returns the target path

2) **registry.targetpoint** : Returns the target path

3) **registry.link** : Returns true/false, check whether the given path is symlink or not.

4) **registry.author** : owner of the resource.

When user delete the target resource, Governance Registry automatically delete the symlink.
Therefore broken link doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you.  I was using `registry.getMetaData("symlink path")` and that was not returning the properties you mentioned.  Changing the code to use the `registry.get(...)` made it work.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to obtain broken links by having 2 symlinks point to the same resource.  When you delete the resource, only 1 of the symlinks gets deleted. The other one is broken.  You cannot see this in the UI interface, but can see it in a call to `collection.getChildren()` of the parent collection of the symlink.

Comment: Filed a [bug report](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1604) in the WSO2 JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

Found that if a `resource.getMediaType()` returns `RegistryConstants.LINK_MEDIA_TYPE` it means that this is a broken link whose target (the resource it was pointing to) was deleted.

Furthermore, found that all symlink information in G-Reg is stored in the following registry location:
`/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/mount`

Each entry in that location represents a symbolic link, and details about the symbolic link can be obtained from the properties associated with the entries in the location above. These properties include:

- `author` - the user who created the symlink
- `path` - the location of the symlink
- `target` - the target of the symlink

Comment: To follow up, is there any API that allows me to obtain the symlink information without having to manually look for entries in the above location and parse properties?

Comment: I discovered why in some instances the `resource.getMediaType()` returned `RegistryConstants.LINK_MEDIA_TYPE` and in other cases it returned the target's media type: when using `resource = registry.get("symlink_path")`, then `getMediaType()` returns the target media type;  when using `resource = registry.getMetaData("symlink_path")`, then `getMediaType()` returns the `RegistryConstants.LINK_MEDIA_TYPE` value. The difference is in how the resource instance was obtained.